# Sum values in one column of a 2d array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [f_count] => 1 [uid] => 105 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 106 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [f_count] => 2 [uid] => 107 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 108 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [f_count] => 1 [uid] => 109 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 110 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [f_count] => 3 [uid] => 111 )
)
```

What I need is: `7`", which is the the sum of the `f_count` column.

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple hours. I thought [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) would work, but not with a multidimensional array. So, I've tried figuring out how to isolate the `f_count`s by `unset()` or splicing or anything else, but every solution seems to involve a `foreach` loop. I've messed with `array_map`, `array_walk`, and others to no avail. I haven't found a function that works well with multidimensional arrays.

I'm running PHP 5.4.

Can someone please show me how to sum that column without a `foreach` loop?

If it helps, the `f_count` values will never be higher than `100`, and the `uid` values will always be greater than `100`.

---

Alternatively, if there's a way to run my query differently such that the array is not multidimensional, that would obviously work as well.

```
$query = "SELECT f_count, uid FROM users WHERE gid=:gid";
...
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I'm using PDO.

Comment: You cannot do anything with an array without looping. Why are you so averse to it?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to couple it with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to select the `f_count` column first:

```
array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
    return $item['f_count']; 
}, $arr));
```

Nowadays you can replace the inner function with [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/array_column):

```php
array_sum(array_column($arr, 'f_count'));
```

Of course, internally, this performs a double loop; it's just that you don't see it inside the code. You could use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) to get rid of one loop:

```
array_reduce($arr, function(&$res, $item) {
    return $res + $item['f_count'];
}, 0);
```

However, if speed is the only interest, `foreach` remains the fastest:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $sum += $item['f_count'];
}
```

This is thanks to the "locality" of the variables that you're using, i.e. there are no function calls used to calculate the final sum.

Comment: I'm not being too presumptuous thinking that these options are likely to be more efficient than foreach?

Comment: @David No, they're both less efficient than `foreach`.

Comment: I guess I was misinformed.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I'd give you a bonus if I could for also coming up with a `foreach` that's prettier and simpler than the others I've seen.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 123):

In php 5.5+ you can just used `array_column` and `array_sum` like so:

```
 $value = array_sum(array_column($arr,'f_count'));
```

Comment: thanks man, now i can sleep well. my version is not to sum, but just to count, so I use this function =>  `$value = array_count_values(array_column($arr,'f_count'));`

Comment: "... multidimensional array ..." what about a case where depth is, say, `3`?

Answer (score 2):

for these type of situation foreach loop is the best possible option but if u have to do this for multiple times on a single page then u should put foreach loop in a function so that your code remain clean

```
function sum_index($arr, $col_name){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $sum += $item[$col_name];
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

**Edit**

After searching alot I found that `array_column` function exist in php 5.5 + to get all values of single column as an array.

For users having lower version You can use following function and call it with array sum if you want sum of all values as well.

```
//to get all values of single column from multidimensional array, this function exist in php 5.5 or greater.
if(!function_exists("array_column"))
{
    function array_column($array,$column_name)
    {
        return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return $element[$column_name];}, $array);
    }
}
```

If you want to get all values of single column then call above function like this:

```
$newArray = array_column($array,$column_name);
```

If you want sum of all values of single column then use following code:

```
$newArraySum = array_sum(array_column($array,$column_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively, if there's a way to run my query differently such that
>   the array is not multidimensional, that would obviously work as well.
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT f_count, uid FROM users WHERE gid=:gid"; 
> ... 
> $array = $stmt->fetchAll();
> ```
>
> I'm using PDO.

Yes, there is another way to run your query differently. You could use the aggregate function [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to get the sum of all the `f_count` directly in your query. You would combine this with `$stmt->fetchColumn()` to get the value of the first column (which would be the sum) of the first row (which will be the only row since we used an aggregate function).

Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(f_count) FROM users WHERE gid=:gid";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':gid' => 'yoursearchvalue'));
$sum = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP 5.4 with PDO, there could be one more way to do it (available in PHP 5.1+):

- use the PDO `fetchAll()` function with the `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` as the `fetch_style`, and the 0-indexed column number as the `fetch_argument`.

As per your example, it could be:

```
$query = "SELECT f_count, uid FROM users WHERE gid=:gid";
...
$array_fcount = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Now use the `array_sum` function to sum the values of the array:

```
$fcount_sum = array_sum($array_fcount);
```

You could also consult the PHP documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Hope this helps, and the performance could be better than looping! As already mentioned in other answers, in PHP 5.5 onwards you have the `array_column()` function to get `$array_fcount` directly from another array.