# sum key values of two arrays by using other key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 8000
            [date] => 2015-04-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 5000
            [date] => 2015-04-02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 5000
            [date] => 2015-04-10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 25000
            [date] => 2015-04-20
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-01
            [amount] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-02
            [amount] => 5000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-03
            [amount] => 2000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-10
            [amount] => 2000
        )

)
```

I have two arrays with keys and values. sum the 'amount' key if 'date' key values is same

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-01
            [amount] => 9000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-02
            [amount] => 10000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-03
            [amount] => 2000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-10
            [amount] => 7000
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-04-20
            [amount] => 25000
        )
)
```

Comment: show us some of your work/progress?

Comment: and what have you tried so far??

Comment: What's your question? Where are you stuck? Also, please don't tag-spam: Do you want to do this in PHP, or JavaScript? Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also, this kind of problem can be easily solved by doing some research. remember: Google is your friend

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum values of multidimensional array by key without loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop)

Comment: i want to sum the amount value if the date is same and remaining values are need to be print as it is..

Comment: [x] => Array
        (
            `[date] => 2015-04-10
            [amount] => 7000`
        ) this should be an object not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution -

```
<?php
$array_result = array();

$array1=array(  // your first array

0 => Array
        (
            'amount' => 8000,
            'date' => '2015-04-01'
        ),

1 => Array
    (
        'amount' => 5000,
        'date' => '2015-04-02'
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'amount' => 5000,
        'date' => '2015-04-10'
    ),

3 => Array
    (
        'amount' => 25000,
        'date' => '2015-04-20'
    )
);

$array2=array(  // your second array

0 => Array
        (
            'date' => '2015-04-01',
            'amount' => 1000
        ),

1 => Array
    (
        'date' =>'2015-04-02',
        'amount' => 5000
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'date' => '2015-04-03',
        'amount' => 2000
    ),

3 => Array
    (
        'date' => '2015-04-10',
        'amount' => 2000
    )
);

$array_result = $array2; // default value of result will be array2

function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

foreach( $array1 as $k1=>$val1  ) {
    $is_exist = recursive_array_search($val1['date'], $array_result);
    if( $is_exist !== false )
    {
        $array_result[ $is_exist ]['amount']+=$val1['amount'];
    } else {
        $array_result[]=$val1;
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r( $array_result );

?>
```

Comment: thank you prakash its working, but they cant not showing order(date) wise.

Comment: Please vote up. You need to create another array which have date as key and amount as value, then sort by date, it will give you your desire result.