# Sum column values from qualifying rows of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, filtering

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 16800
                    [created] => 1438114651
                    [status] => pending
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 16800
                    [created] => 1435854159
                    [status] => available
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 3300
                    [created] => 1435711645
                    [status] => available
                )
        )
)
```

I need to filter this array the `sum of the amounts` only with the `available status` and between two created dates?

Do I need a `foreach`?

Comment: no, you don't need a foreach. a regular `for` would work as well...

Comment: Slightly different filtering / multidimensional concerns:  but good info still on these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
function totalAmount($array, $start = 0, $end = 1E+11) {
    $totalAvailable = 0;
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if(
            $item['status'] == 'available'
            && $item['created'] >= $start
            && $item['created'] < $end
            ) $totalAvailable += $item['amount'];
    }
    return $totalAvailable
}

$sum = totalAmount($foo['data'], $unixtimeStart, $unixtimeEnd);
```

I used `>=` for the start condition, but you can adjust if needed.
Also, the start and end parameters are now optional.

Comment: Works, but, no `array_sum`?  I personally like the linked answer more.

Comment: Thanks. Works for the first part. What about the datas filtering?

Comment: hmm, OK, didn't see that date range criteria part before.  Still another native array function... array_map comes to mind.

Comment: I missed the 'between' portion of your question.  Updating the answer to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$data=    Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 16800
                    [created] => 1438114651
                    [status] => pending
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 16800
                    [created] => 1435854159
                    [status] => available
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 3300
                    [created] => 1435711645
                    [status] => available
                )
        )
)

$createdFrom = ...; // from date
$createdTo=...; // to date
$total=0;
foreach($data['data'] as $array)
    if($array['created'] > $createdfrom && $array['created'] < $createdTo) 
        if($array['status']=="available")
            $total+=$array['amount'];
echo $total;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I have juste change your `>` and `<` to `>=` and  `<=`.