# how to calculate data in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

guys is that possible to calculate between `(+,-,*,/)` in multidimensional array?

example i have a multidimensional array in `$menu_info` with this following code :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["menu_order_id"]=>
    string(3) "190"
    ["menu_name"]=>
    string(13) "Golden Salmon"
    ["menu_variant"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "15.4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["menu_order_id"]=>
    string(3) "191"
    ["menu_name"]=>
    string(13) "Golden Salmon"
    ["menu_variant"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "15.4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["menu_order_id"]=>
    string(3) "192"
    ["menu_name"]=>
    string(13) "Golden Salmon"
    ["menu_variant"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "15.4"
  }
}
```

i want trying to calculate all of the `price*qty` like `(15*1)+(15*1)+(15*1)`
guys how to count the multidimensional array using math operator ?

thank you very much (:

p.s the length of array can be change.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['price']*$item['qty'];
}, $menu_info));
```

With some more explanation on your specific issue, I may be able to assist you in better alternatives.

Comment: which part i need to explain more?, my array are in `$menu_info`

Comment: You are welcome ;) If this solves the problem, you should mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).