# how to get the sum of the values of some arrays inside an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum

How can I get the total deposit and total withdraw combined for each month? e.g (all January month total deposit and total withdraw) from an array.

Actually, I have some table (100+). Each table has so many records with deposit, withdraw and date column fields. I have to sum the deposit and withdraw value with grouped by date.

Indeed, I got the monthly total deposit and total withdraw amount for each table. Now, I have to sum each month from all tables. e.g, Total deposit and withdraw of Jaunuary of all tables.

In my CI Controller:

```
$all_table_id = $this->admin_model->get_all_id();

foreach ($all_table_id as $table_id)
{
    // $table_id['accountNo'] is generated table name 
    // e.g baby_ld_account_45456 ,baby_ld_account_12345

    $tableName = "baby_ld_account_" . $table_id['accountNo'];

    $single_table_monthly_data = $this->admin_model->get_monthly_data_each_table($tableName);

    // print_r($single_table_monthly_data);

    $all_table_monthly_data[] = $single_table_monthly_data;

    print_r($monthly_data);
}
```

In my CI model:

```
public function get_monthly_data_each_table($tableName) {
    $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`entryDate`,'%M') as Month, 
                   SUM(`deposit`) AS `Deposit`, 
                   SUM(`withDraw`) AS `Withdraw` 
            FROM $tableName 
            WHERE YEAR(`entryDate`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`entryDate`,'%M')";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array($query);

    return $result;
}
```

Array result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [Month] => January [Deposit] => 4000 [Withdraw] => 8000 )
        [1] => Array ( [Month] => February [Deposit] => 200 [Withdraw] => 5000 )
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [Month] => January [Deposit] => 1000 [Withdraw] => 1000 )
        [1] => Array ( [Month] => February [Deposit] => 3000 [Withdraw] => 6000 )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [Month] => January [Deposit] => 6000 [Withdraw] => 2000 )
        [1] => Array ( [Month] => February [Deposit] => 4000 [Withdraw] => 8000 )
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [Month] => January [Deposit] => 3500 [Withdraw] => 2000 )
        [1] => Array ( [Month] => February [Deposit] => 1200 [Withdraw] => 5000 )
    )
)
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Please paste you code/array and expected result

Comment: You tagged with MySQL and the first thing which comes to mind is that you should try doing this in the database, before you bring the nested array mess into PHP.

Comment: Tim might have a point, but actually you should be able to do this just as effectively in PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop/16138430#16138430) can help you...

Comment: i am still not found any solution. can anybody help me out?

Comment: Did you check the link I provided?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this was pointed in comments, this better to be done with SQL query.

But you sure can do it with PHP:

```
$result = array_reduce(
    array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []), // Flattern array.
    function ($result, $item) {
        // Extract array elements to variables, for the sake of easier use.
        extract($item);

        // If there's no entry for current month - create emtpy entry.
        if (!isset($result[$Month])) {
            $result[$Month] = [
                'Deposit' => 0,
                'Withdraw' => 0
            ];
        }

        // Add current amounts.
        $result[$Month]['Deposit'] += $Deposit;
        $result[$Month]['Withdraw'] += $Withdraw;

        return $result;
    },
    []
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5dcea4e329e169c01e4543acb371b5fdc373891).

Comment: @sevavietl.How can i get the array with month name also? e.g( array([0]=>array([Month]=>'January' [Deposit] => 14500 [Withdraw] => 13000)) ) from your given demo.

Comment: @RiyadhAhmed, you can add `'Month' => $Month,` to `$result[$Month] = [
                'Deposit' => 0,
                'Withdraw' => 0
            ];`

Comment: @sevavietl.Can you help me once more? Actually every thing is fine but a little problem is if a table hasn't any data of a month e.g(February..) the array month is not ordering the ascending order e.g('January','February','March'...). It is viewing like ('January','March','December'...). i added ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`entryDate`,'%m') in my model query and it orders fine but in the controller array $all_table_monthly_data[] it not ordering correctly because of if a table hasn't the month name.

Comment: @RiyadhAhmed, so the question is how to order this final array of sums by month?

Comment: @sevavietl.Yes.

Comment: @RiyadhAhmed, try this `usort($result, function ($a, $b) {return date_parse($a['Month'])["month"] - date_parse($b['Month'])["month"];});`.