# How to sum values in multi dimensional arrays as in a given format

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an array with some keys, here what I need is to sum values at same keys e.g., scorecard value for key 117 & 917 should sum up and assign to key 53 as given below in the output array:-

```
$input_array = array(

53 => array
    (
        117 => array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        'q1' => 1,
                        'q2' => 0,
                        'q3' => 0,
                        'q4' => 1
                    )

            ),

        917 => array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        'q1' => 1,
                        'q2' => 0,
                        'q3' => 0,
                        'q4' => 1
                    )

            )
    ),

38 => array
    (
        414 => array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        'q1' => 1,
                        'q2' => 0,
                        'q3' => 1,
                        'q4' => 0
                    ),

                'business_plan' => array
                    (
                        'q1' => 1,
                        'q2' => 0,
                        'q3' => 0,
                        'q4' => 0
                    )

            ),

        '107' => Array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        'q1' => 1,
                        'q2' => 1,
                        'q3' => 1,
                        'q4' => 0
                    )

            )
    )

);
```

Output array will contain values like this:-

```
[53] => Array
    (

        [scorecard] => Array
            (
                [q1] => 2
                [q2] => 0
                [q3] => 0
                [q4] => 2
            )

     )    

[38] => Array
    (

        [scorecard] => Array
               (
                    [q1] => 2
                    [q2] => 1
                    [q3] => 2
                    [q4] => 0
                )

        [business_plan] => Array
                (
                    [q1] => 1
                    [q2] => 0
                    [q3] => 0
                    [q4] => 0
                )
    )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop

Comment: Ok, Anant but I'm not able to figure out how to apply array_map, array_reduce function with given input array.