# Sum a column's values in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, array-column

I have a 2d array like this:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Banana', 'quantity' => 124],
    ['name' => 'Cherry', 'quantity' => 24],
    ['name' => 'Apple', 'quantity' => 224],
]
```

How can I sum the numbers with the key `quantity`? (372)

Comment: This question is related with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, always share with us what you have tried.

It help us a lot.

You can use:

```
$arr = [['name' => "Banana", 'quantity' => 124], ['name' => "Cherry", 'quantity' => 24], ['name' => "Apple", 'quantity' => 224]];

$sum = 0;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $sum += $item['quantity'];
}
```

Or (PHP 5.5+):

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'quantity'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    Receives a Multidemensional Array (Matrix) and returns the sum of quantity.
    Returns -1 on fail.
*/
function SumKeyOfArray($Matrix)
{
    if(!empty($Matrix))
    {
        $sum = 0;       
        foreach($Matrix as $array)
        {
            if(isset($array['quantity']))
                $sum = $sum + $array['quantity'];
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the reduce function:

```
$arr= [['name' => "Banana", 'quantity' => 124], ['name' => "Cherry", 'quantity' => 24], ['name' => "Apple", 'quantity' => 224]];

echo array_reduce($arr, function($sum, $elem) {
    return $sum += $elem["quantity"];
});
```