# Read through JSON field and sum without foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have the following Laravel collection:

`$sum = $payments->where('status', 'Executed')->pluck('request_text')`

`request_text` is a JSON field that has an `amount` property inside. Is there a way I can sum all that amount without looping through a `json_decode` with a `foreach`? Maybe some method equivalent to `pluck` but for extracting from JSON?

Comment: The link below should solve that for you.
[Sum array without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might achieve the result using [type casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) and [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sum) method:

```
class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'request_text' => 'object',
    ];

    public function getAmountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->request_text->amount;
    }
}


// Both of these are gonna work.
$sum = Payment::whereStatus('Executed')->sum(function ($payment) {
    return $payment->request_text->amount;
});

$sum = Payment::whereStatus('Executed')->sum->amount;
```

You can also cast the request_text to array so you can access the amount a bit differently.

```
class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'request_text' => 'array',
    ];

    public function getAmountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->request_text['amount'];
    }
}
```