# Php multidimensional array filter and sum

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

i've a multidimensional array like this one:

```
['2021-04-01'=>
      ['hb' => 35, 'fb' => 40, 'ai' => 50],
'2021-04-02'=>
      ['hb' => 35, 'fb' => 40, 'ai' => 50],
'2021-04-03'=>
      ['hb' => 40, 'ai' => 55],
'2021-04-04'=>
      ['hb' => 40, 'fb' => 45, 'ai' => 55],
'2021-04-05'=>
      ['hb' => 35, 'ai' => 50]]
```

I'd like to receive an array like this one:

```
['hb'=>185,'ai'=>260]
```

Basically i've to **sum the price of every single treatment** (hb=half-board, fb=full board, ai=all inclusive) **only if** the treatment is present in every element of the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values of multidimensional array by key without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the foreach loop is propably the best option. Although you can use `array_sum` function after `array_map`. Example for `foreach`:

```
$ret = []
foreach ($input_array as $second_array) {
     foreach ($second_array as $key => $value) {
         if (!isset($ret[$key]))
              $ret[$key] = 0;
         $ret[$key] += $value
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution with [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce.php).

```
$sum = array_reduce($arr ,function($carry,$val){
    return ['hb'=>$carry['hb']+$val['hb'],'ai'=>$carry['ai']+$val['ai']];
  },
  ['hb'=>0,'ai'=>0]
);
```

$arr is your input-array, $sum the result.

More understandable what array_reduce makes is a simple loop with foreach.

```
$sum = ['hb' => 0, 'ai' => 0];
foreach($arr as $row){
  $sum['hb'] += $row['hb'];
  $sum['ai'] += $row['ai'];
}
```